# Testing in Rails. Seems it deletes records within one test run. Ideas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

Let's take a look at the next scenario:

```
Scenario: Show welcome feed
  Given log me in
  When I'm on "profile" page
  Then Page should have content "You are welcome"
```

Pretty simple. What about `log me in` step?

```
Given /^log me in$/ do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create :user, email: 'user@mail.ru', password: '12345678', username: '
  visit sign_in_path
  fill_in 'user_email', with: 'user@mail.ru'
  fill_in 'user_password', with: '12345678'
  click_on 'Enter'
end
```

Nothing complex. But when I run this scenario it can't log me in because there is no user with provided email. Lol what? It happens with other scenarios where I trying to create and log in user.

- It's a **global issue**. I can't create and test any records.
- It worked before, **there weren't any changes in scenarios and steps**.
- It works
  in **development** and **production** environment. So it's environment issue I guess.

Any ideas? How to debug this?

Comment: do you use `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` gem to see it in rails console `FactoryGirl.create ` please let me know

Comment: also  `rake db:test:prepare`  ran ?

Comment: I use ```factory_girl_rails```

Comment: db:test:prepare is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically

Answer (score 0):

Your data is removed after each test because of this line

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Try to change this to `false` then your data will be persistent. For more information, please see the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions).

However, it is not good to keep the data persistent all the time. I'd recommend using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to manage the data yourself. It is very well documented for capybara/cucumber.

Comment: It's not removed after each test, it removed **within** one test suite. That's the problem.

Comment: From [Capybara docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup): "Since transactions are usually not shared across threads, this will cause data you have put into the database in your test code to be invisible to Capybara."

Comment: Did you set truncation instead of transaction?

Comment: Set, nothing changed.

Comment: Please update your question with database_cleaner config

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say exactly without the configs you're using, but since you say it used to work we'll assume the configs are all correct.  If that is the case, and you're "When I'm on ... page" step is actually visiting a page and not just checking current path, then what you're most likely experiencing is the fact that capybara actions are not guaranteed to be synchronous - ie the call to any action in Capybara may return before the action/side effects triggered by that action have completed.  In this case the `click_on 'Enter'` submits your log in info but doesn't wait for the login to actually complete.  If the `When I'm on "profile" page` then executes a new visit action before the login fully completes there will be no cookies set in the browser to identify it as logged in. Therefore trying to access the profile page will act as if the user isn't logged in.  What you need to add is a final line in your 'log me in' step that confirms the login has completed - something like

```
expect(page).to have_text('You are now logged in') # whatever text shows up when a user successfully logs in
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_selector('#user_menu') # selector for some element that is only on pages when a user is logged in
```

Comment: I've tested it via Selenium and I see record not found error from devise.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide more details of your configs, exact error messages, logs, etc in the question for anyone to have a chance of figuring out your issue